# A syntax error when defining variable within a function

Tags: python-3.x

```
def isPalindrome(x: int) -> bool:
    #get each digit and save in a list
    num = []
    for i in range(1,11):
        if (x % (10**(i-1) != x)):
            num.append((x % (10**i)) // (10**(i-1)) 
    #reverse the digits
    num_rev = num[::-1]
    #compare
    if (num_rev == num):
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Why I have syntax error when defining the variable num_rev? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Probably because you forget to close the bracket

`num.append((x % (10**i)) // (10**(i-1)))`

Comment: how could you figure this out in such a quick look :P

Comment: The error message provides some hints. Most of the `SyntaxError` , from my experience, are caused because of typo, mismatch bracket.